# Error en base de datos acces c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access-2013

introducir el código aquí

```
public partial class Frm_Agregar_Nuevos : Form
{
    public Frm_Agregar_Nuevos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Cmb_Cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Frm_Agregar_Nuevos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Bloquer controles
        Interface_Inicial();


    }


    private void Interface_Inicial()
    {

        Lab_Id.Enabled = true;
        Tex_id.Enabled = true;
        Cmb_Buscar.Enabled = true;
        Cmb_Cancelar.Enabled = true;

        lab_Nombre.Enabled = false;
        lab_Direccion.Enabled = false;
        lab_Edad.Enabled = false;

        Tex_Nombre.Enabled = false;
        Tex_Direccion.Enabled = false;
        Tex_Edad.Enabled = false;

        Cmb_Guardar.Enabled = false;

        Tex_id.Focus();
    }

    private void Cmb_Buscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Buscar_Registro(Tex_id.Text) == false)
        {
            Interface_Datos();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("El registro ya existe");
            Tex_id.Focus();
        }


    }

    private bool  Buscar_Registro(string Codigo)
    {
        // Convertir Cadena A Numero

        int Cod = Convert.ToInt32(Codigo); 

        //Conexion a la base de datos acces
        OleDbConnection conexion = new OleDbConnection();
        conexion.ConnectionString = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE,ALEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\\BBDDEmpres.accdb; Persist Security Info=false ";

        // Cadena sql

        String CadenaSQL = "SELECT * FROM Personal WHERE id= "+ Cod;

        //Adaptador
        OleDbDataAdapter Adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter(CadenaSQL,conexion);


        //Dataset contenedor 
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        //Llenar el dataset

       conexion.Open();
        Adaptador.Fill(ds);

        conexion.Close();

        //Contar registro
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {

            return false;//El registro no fue encontrado

        }
        else
        {
            return true;//El registro existe
        }




    }


    private void Interface_Datos()
    {

        Lab_Id.Enabled = false;
        Tex_id.Enabled = false;
        Cmb_Buscar.Enabled = false;
        Cmb_Cancelar.Enabled = true;

        lab_Nombre.Enabled = true;
        lab_Direccion.Enabled = true;
        lab_Edad.Enabled = true;

        Tex_Nombre.Enabled = true;
        Tex_Direccion.Enabled = true;
        Tex_Edad.Enabled = true;

        Cmb_Guardar.Enabled =true;

        Tex_Nombre.Focus();


    }

    private void Cmb_Guardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Limpiar_Formulario();//Permite limpiar el formulario 
        Interface_Inicial();//Prepara la interfaz antes de abrir los datos


    }

    private void Limpiar_Formulario()
    {
        Tex_Nombre.Clear();
        Tex_Direccion.Clear();
        Tex_Edad.Clear();
    }
}
```

[image: Ejecutando el prorama y colocando Una ID]

[image: Error]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Organiza tu pregunta. Cual es el problema?? el error debe ir como texto. Donde de todo ese codigo ocurre el error? que tiene que ver la pantalla que estas mostrando?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cuando tienes ese error es porque debes instalar el redistribuible de `ACE.OLEDB.12`

Lo descargas de aqui

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

aqui se menciona mas sobre el problema

[Installing the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider for Both 64-bit and 32-bit Processing](https://datasavvy.me/2017/07/20/installing-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-for-both-64-bit-and-32-bit-processing/)

Comment: muchas gracias ya esta solucionado

Comment: quien vota negativo puede explicar porque? asi ayuda a mejorar si es que cree falto algo en la respuesta